# vue router not updating url with new data of same object

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

i have a vue login form thats returns the errors as a query. after the first error the query object is loaded the the error string, the subsequent once are not even if they show up in the console...

store.js...

```
userLogin({ commit }, { email, password }) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(user => {
          commit("setUser", user);
          commit("setIsAuthenticated", true);
          console.log("User: " + user.user.uid + "found")
          router.push("/dashboard");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          commit("setUser", null);
          commit("setIsAuthenticated", false);
          console.log("Login Error: " + error.message);
          router.go({name: "signin", force: true,  query: {errorMessage: error.message, signinError: true}});
        });
    },
```

signin script....

```
    data() {
        return {
          email: "",
          password: "",
          performingRequest: false,
          signinError: false,
          signupSuccessful: false,
          errorMessage: "",
          successMessage: ""
        };
      },
      created() {
        if(this.$route.query.signinError) {
          this.signinError = this.$route.query.signinError;
          this.errorMessage = this.$route.query.errorMessage;
        }
      },
methods: {
    validateStep(scope) {
      this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.performingRequest = true
          this.$store.dispatch("userLogin", {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          })
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

signin template....

```
<v-alert :value="signinError" type="error" >
          {{errorMessage}}
          </v-alert>
          <v-alert :value="signupSuccessful" type="success" >
          {{successMessage}}
          </v-alert>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question...but from a glance, I spotted an issue:
This: `router.go();` is now: `router.push();`
Check this doc out: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Let me know if you need further help.